# How to notification to android remotely?

Tags: java, android

Is there anyway in android to send a code or something to a device with an app installed and cause the device to show a notification or vibrate?

What would be the best way to do this?

like a PC you have the ability to send a specific code to the device with the app installed and cause it to do a notification..
What is the best way to do this or go about doing this?

Any ideas will be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, in general they are called push notications.  Check out Android's [Cloud 2 Device Messaging](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html) system.

Comment: SO how will it be able to show a notification or make a device vibrate or ring?

Comment: Setup a service that recieves Push notications. When the service receives one, it can then create a system notification.